# generator of cartesian products of one list

Tags: python

How do I create a generator of cartesian products of one list without itertools or any imports?
I tried doing a simple
for x in iterable[0]:
for y in iterable[1]:
yield (x: y)

but it doesn't work for all cases

```
list = [(1,2), (2,3)]
output = (1, 2), (1,3), (2, 2), (2,3)
```

the results should look like this

Comment: There is "itertools.product" for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You seem to be thinking that StackOverflow is here to give you your answer. That is a misunderstanding, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
for i in product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
    print(i)
# (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6)
```

without itertools you can use recursion like this

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def generate_product(*args):
    if not args:
        return
    if len(args) == 1:
        return (i for i in args[0])
    i = args[0]
    return ((j, *k) if isinstance(k, Iterable) else (j,k) for k in generate_product(*args[1:]) for j in i )

for i in generate_product([1, 1], [2, 2]):
    print(i, end=" ")
for i in generate_product('BC', 'CD', 'DF'):
    print(i, end=" ")
# (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2)
# ('B', 'C', 'D') ('C', 'C', 'D') ('B', 'D', 'D') ('C', 'D', 'D') ('B', 'C', 'F') ('C', 'C', 'F') ('B', 'D', 'F') ('C', 'D', 'F')
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without itertools? thats the goal here for me

Comment: @willywonka I have added the implementation without itertools

Comment: How do you do it without importing anything at all?

Comment: You need to go through the recursion to see how it's building this.